# Tkinker text enter for bet

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textinput

I'm trailing another idea of allowing a user to enter a bet between 10 & 100 coins. Which then needs to be saved onto the next page of the GUI. I've tried a few codes but I can't get anything to override what is there and any attempts to remove it and add in a code for the user to input how much they want to bet. Could a code like that be placed into a class to make it different from the rest?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

intro = """Panther's Den Slot Machine.


Welcome to my den!

You can win by rolling Ocelots, Jaguars, Boas, Caimans, Macaws or Tapirs.
You can also with big with three Ibis.

You'll lose a coin for anything else, and if you roll three Scorpions say good bye to 500 coins

Good luck kit!"""


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")
root.title("Slot Machine")
root.configure(background='seagreen')

INIT_STAKE = 100
ITEMS = ["OCELOT", "MACAW", "JAGUAR", "IBIS", "CAIMAN", "BOA", "SCORPION", "TAPIR", "CONDOR", "BAMBOO", "FROG"]

first = None
second = None
third = None
stake = INIT_STAKE

nameLabel = tk.Label(root, text="PANTHER DEN", font=('Cambria', 60))
nameLabel.pack()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text=intro, background='seagreen', font=('Cambria', 12))
lbl.pack()
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text=stake)
lbl2.pack()

def play():
    global first, second, third
    first = spin()
    second = spin()
    third = spin()
    score()

def quit_play():
    lbl.config(text="Game has ended. You won a total of " + str(stake) + " coins")

def spin():
    randomnumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    return ITEMS[randomnumber]

def score():
    global stake, first, second, third
    if((first == "OCELOT") and (second != "MACAW")):
        win = 5
    elif((first == "JAGUAR") and (second == "JAGUAR") and (third != "JAGUAR")):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "BOA") and (second == "BOA") and (third == "BOA")):
        win = 10
    elif((first == "CAIMAN") and (second == "CAIMAN") and ((third == "CAIMAN") or (third == "BOA"))):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "MACAW") and (second == "IBIS") and ((third == "MACAW"))):
        win = 15
    elif((first == "TAPIR") and (second == "TAPIR") and ((third == "TAPIR"))):
        win = 20
    elif((first == "IBIS") and (second == "IBIS") and (third == "IBIS")):
        win = 300
    elif((first == "SCORPION") and (second == "SCORPION") and (third == "SCORPION")):
        win = -500
    else:
        win = -1

    stake += win

    if(win > 0):
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You win {} Coins".format(first, second, third, win))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)
    else:
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You lose".format(first, second, third))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)


tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit_play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class RollMachine(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.first = self.second = self.third = None
    self.stake = 0
    self.intro = """Panther's Den Slot Machine.


    Welcome to my den!

    You can win by rolling Ocelots, Jaguars, Boas, Caimans, Macaws or Tapirs.
    You can also with big with three Ibis.

    You'll lose a coin for anything else, and if you roll three Scorpions say 
    good bye to 500 coins

    Good luck kit!"""
    self.ITEMS = ["OCELOT", "MACAW", "JAGUAR", "IBIS", "CAIMAN", "BOA", "SCORPION", "TAPIR", "CONDOR", "BAMBOO", "FROG"]

    self.makeWidgets()
    self.pack()

def makeWidgets(self):
    nameLabel = Label(self, text="PANTHER DEN", font=('Cambria', 60))
    nameLabel.pack()
    self.lbl = Label(self, text=self.intro, background='seagreen', font=('Cambria', 12))
    self.lbl.pack()
    self.lbl2 = Label(self, text="Enter the stake")
    self.lbl2.pack()
    self.stake_input = Entry(self)
    self.stake_input.pack()
    Button(self, text="Play", command=self.play).pack()
    Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit_play).pack()
    Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.quit).pack()

def play(self):
            if self.stake == 0:
                self.stake = int(self.stake_input.get())
            self.first = self.spin()
            self.second = self.spin()
            self.third = self.spin()
            self.score()

def spin(self):
    randomnumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    return self.ITEMS[randomnumber]

def score(self):
    if((self.first == "OCELOT") and (self.second != "MACAW")):
        win = 5
    elif((self.first == "JAGUAR") and (self.second == "JAGUAR") and (self.third != "JAGUAR")):
        win = 8 
    elif((self.first == "BOA") and (self.second == "BOA") and (self.third == "BOA")):
        win = 10
    elif((self.first == "CAIMAN") and (self.second == "CAIMAN") and ((self.third == "CAIMAN") or (self.third == "BOA"))):
        win = 8 
    elif((self.first == "MACAW") and (self.second == "IBIS") and ((self.third == "MACAW"))):
        win = 15 
    elif((self.first == "TAPIR") and (self.second == "TAPIR") and ((self.third == "TAPIR"))):
        win = 20 
    elif((self.first == "IBIS") and (self.second == "IBIS") and (self.third == "IBIS")):
        win = 300 
    elif((self.first == "SCORPION") and (self.second == "SCORPION") and (self.third == "SCORPION")):
        win = -500 
    else:
        win = -1 

    self.stake += win

    if(win > 0):
        self.lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You win {} Coins".format(self.first, self.second, self.third, win))
        self.lbl2.config(text=self.stake)
    else:
        self.lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You lose".format(self.first, self.second, self.third))
        self.lbl2.config(text=self.stake)

def quit_play(self):
    self.lbl.config(text="Game has ended. You won a total of " + str(self.stake) + " coins")




root = Tk()
RollMachine(root)
```

Comment: It doesn't partly work. I'm able to enter a number (Actually you have to) but when you continue to start rolling the game it runs of the original number of coins (100) rather then the number you enter

Comment: You were asked to do so that you could specify the bet, and the amount of coins decreased or increased depending on the size of the bet. If you need to change the value of the initial number of coins, then this is done quite simply, you just have to try a little.

Comment: Check now. Edited to write down in the initial amount